# IS NULL check performs worse in ON clause compared to WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

This query runs just fine but if I move the `AND h2.delete_datetime IS NULL` condition from the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause of the left join the query takes forever. This baffles me because I am used to putting as many conditions as possible into `ON` clauses to increase performance (More conditions in the `ON` clause means less rows joined and less rows to consider). Here the opposite seems to be true and I am wondering why.

good:

```
SELECT
 count(*),
 min(h.history_date) AS history_date
FROM
 history AS h
LEFT JOIN
 history AS h2
ON (
     h2.contacts_id = h.contacts_id
 AND h2.history_status_id = 59
 /*AND h2.delete_datetime IS NULL*/
)
WHERE
     h.history_status_id = 58
 AND h2.contacts_id IS NULL
 AND h.delete_datetime IS NULL
 AND h2.delete_datetime IS NULL
ORDER BY h.history_date DESC
```

vs bad:

```
SELECT
 count(*),
 min(h.history_date) AS history_date
FROM
 history AS h
LEFT JOIN
 history AS h2
ON (
     h2.contacts_id = h.contacts_id
 AND h2.history_status_id = 59
 AND h2.delete_datetime IS NULL
)
WHERE
     h.history_status_id = 58
 AND h2.contacts_id IS NULL
 AND h.delete_datetime IS NULL
 /*AND h2.delete_datetime IS NULL*/
ORDER BY h.history_date DESC
```

Comment: In principle it should not matter as the optimizer should take care of this (if the queries are comparable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a left join, the queries are *not* equivalent and hence not comparable.

When you put the filter for a column in the right table in `ON` clause, the filter checks if nulls are actually present in the column of your table. The JOIN will still produce nulls for this column when there is not matching row in right table for rows in the left table.

When you put the same filter in `WHERE` clause, the filter check if the nulls are present in the column or if there is no match in the right table for the rows in the left table.